# connect shopify with carrier service

Tags: shopify

Sorry for this question, but I have no ideea how I supposed to do this:

I want to create a connection between shopify and one shipping carrier. I saw that shopify has connection with other carriers (FedEx, UPS) but I want to create another with romanian shipping.

My question is: Can somebody help me with a plan, ideeas or suggestive documentation on how to do this?

I mention that I red about this but I didn't understand very much. I need somebody's help who knows how this works.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Are you on an Advanced Shopify plan or higher? Then you have these options https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice. If not, you can buy a plugin. You do need to make your question more specific, eg. Which carrier do you want to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Contact Shopify support and put in a request for your shipping provider. Will get done.